# Magnetic Flux Linkage of Object

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electromagnetic-induction

$N\phi = $ Magnetic Flux Linkage $ =  BAN\cos\theta$

Where $N$ is the number of coils in a solenoid and $\theta$ is the angle between the normal of the 2D surface and the magnetic field lines.

[image]
<sub>(source: [antonine-education.co.uk](http://www.antonine-education.co.uk/Image_library/Physics_4/Magnetism/Coil_06.JPG))</sub>

Could the Magnetic Flux Linkage of a 3D object, such as a cube, be calculated then by $BV\cos{\theta}$ where $V = H\cdot A = $ Volume.

Would the substitution of $N$ for $H$ be a valid one?

Comment: Not as simply as you put it.  In some specific geometries you can do something that resembles that,  but the result would be correct "by luck".   You can't do what you suggest in general.  Also, note that your suggestion is not dimensionally correct, so the idea would need some development.

Comment: for a cuboid would it work?